# Run-time 1004 error when attempting to Delete Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a procedure which will delete rows if they contain any of the values listed in the array.

At the moment, I'm receiving a run-time 1004 error: Delete method of Range class failed. My sheet is unprotected so I'm not sure why this isn't running. Here's the part which is failing (error is on the EntireRow.Delete line):

```
    With MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(sheet).Rows(1)
    Set b = .Find("CTM flag", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With

' filter and delete all but header row
With b
For i = 0 To 12
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & FlagContent(i)
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
End With
```

This is the whole picture:

```
Sub DeleteNonHET()

    Dim CTMFlag As Long
    
    Dim FlagContent(12) As String
    
    FlagContent(0) = "1"
    FlagContent(1) = "2"
    FlagContent(2) = "3"
    FlagContent(3) = "4"
    FlagContent(4) = "5"
    FlagContent(5) = "8"
    FlagContent(6) = "0"
    FlagContent(7) = "#N/A"
    FlagContent(8) = "G"
    FlagContent(9) = "I"
    FlagContent(10) = "J"
    FlagContent(11) = "L"
    FlagContent(12) = "M"

    'Declaring year value of 1 month & 2 month
    'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
    Year_2M = Format(Date - 57, "YYYY")

    'Declaring month value of 1 month & 2 month
    'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
    Month_2M = Format(Date - 57, "MM")

    'This translates the current month from number to character format
    MonthChar_2 = MonthName(Month_2M, False)

    'opens the workbook before
    'specifiying the file locations
    pStr = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\Monthly Files" & "\" & Year_2M & "\" & _
    Month_2M & ". " & MonthChar_2 & " " & Year_2M & "\"

    myFile = "Dataset"
    otherFile = "Monthly Reporting Tool"
    sheet = "MASTERFILE_" & Year_2M & Month_2M

    'checking to see that dataset wb is open, declaring it as Dataset
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like myFile & "*" Then
           Set Dataset = Workbooks(wb.Name)
        End If
    Next wb
    
    'checking to see that the reporting tool is open, declaring it as MonthlyRepTool
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like otherFile & "*" Then
           Set MonthlyRepTool = Workbooks(wb.Name)
        End If
    Next wb
    
    'counts number of rows in the spreadsheet
    lastRow = MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(sheet).Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        With MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(sheet).Rows(1)
        Set b = .Find("CTM flag", LookIn:=xlValues)
        End With

    For i = 0 To 12
    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With b
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & FlagContent(i)
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    Next i
    
    ' turn off the filters
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: `b` is going to be a 1 field range.  You won't have a `field:=2`

Comment: So I just changed this to **Field:=b.Column** and getting the same error - is this what you meant?

Comment: No.  You will need to include the entire range you intend to filter and delete.  `b` is your filter criteria, not the range to `Autofilter` on.  You are still trying to `Autofilter` a one field range.  It should not be `With b`.

Comment: You're using `SpecialCells` on a single cell, and that has known issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906419/specialcellsxlcelltypeconstants-results-unexpected-result-on-just-one-cell-as

Answer (score 0):

This is the portion of the code that will help establish your filter range

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = MonthlyRepTool.Worksheets(Sheet)

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))


        With ws.Rows(1)
        Set b = .Find("CTM flag", LookIn:=xlValues)
        End With

    For i = 0 To 12
    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
            .AutoFilter Field:=b.Column, Criteria1:="=" & FlagContent(i)
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    Next i
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm still seeing the same run-time error as specified above.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?  You can remove `EntireRow` from your delete statement.  All visible rows will be deleted.